# Storybook build with i18n not worked

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, internationalization, storybook, nuxt3

On a nuxt3 project i have a library of components using storybook

For example this component with a translation:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { t } = useI18n()
</script>

<template>
    <span>{{ t('components.location.backLink.text') }}</span>
</template>
```

This component with i18n works fine when i work on the project (nuxt dev) and when i execute the story.
But when i build the story i can see this following error display:

[image: Story]

The problem is when storybook is build in static we don't have acces to nuxt and the i18n setup.

There is my `i18n.config`:

```
import fr from './translations/fr.json'
import en from './translations/en.json'

export default defineI18nConfig(() => {
  return {
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'en',
    messages: {
      en,
      fr,
    },
  }
})
```

And my `nuxt.config`:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ..., // other config options
  i18n: {
    locales: ['fr', 'en'],
    vueI18n: './i18n/i18n.config.ts',
  },
})
```

I try multiple way, the common is inside the preview file of storybook use the setup function and use `app.use(i18n)`. But every problem solving is for vue3 and seems to not work for my case.

```
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/vue3'
import i18n from '../i18n/i18n.config'

setup((app) => {
  app.use(i18n) // I try createI18n() too, but same error
})

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
}

export default preview
```